# Checking word variants(stems) in java

Tags: java, android

I want to search for a word and its variants in a sentence. For example, the variants of word "happy" are "happiest", "happier". Is there a java library support for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Porter stemming algorithm](http://tartarus.org/~martin/PorterStemmer/) with SQLite on Android by specifying `USING fts3(tokenize=porter)` when you create the virtual table. See the [SQLite FTS documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html) for more details.